# Validate two different input fields in the same form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, function, validation

I have a form where i am validating two different fields, one is tax-number input field and other one is insurance-number field.
I have wrote two corresponding functions for the validation of these fields. How can I write a wrapper function for both of them

**Function for Tax field validation**

```
    validationofTaxIDField(e, formDataArray){
            console.log("WorkflowDisplay: validateTaxIDField: e", e, formDataArray);
            let alertError = false;
            if(formDataArray && formDataArray[0] && formDataArray[0]["1"] && formDataArray[0]["1"].taxInformation){
                const ti = formDataArray[0]["1"].taxInformation;
                console.log("ti", ti);
                if(ti.taxId){
                    if( !validateTIN(ti.taxId) ){ //taxID number
              alertError = true;
            }
                }
            }
            if(alertError){
          alert(customErrorMessages.invalidTaxId);
        }
        }

**Function for Insurance field Validation**
validationofSocialInsuranceField(e, formDataArray){
        console.log("WorkflowDisplay:validateSocialInsuranceField: e" , e, formDataArray);
        let alertError = false;
        if(formDataArray && formDataArray[0] && formDataArray[0]["2"] && formDataArray[0]["2"].insuranceDetails){
            const iid = formDataArray[0]["2"].insuranceDetails;
            console.log("WorkflowDisplay:validateSocialInsuranceField:iid", iid);
            if(iid.insuranceId){
                if( !validateSINo(iid.insuranceId) ){ //taxID number
          alertError = true;
        }
            }
        }
        if(alertError){
      alert(customErrorMessages.invalidInsuranceId);
    }
    }
```

Now when I try to validation even if I am trying to only validate the insurance field it is always throwing me an alert for the tax field. Can someone help me for writing a wrapper function in javascript for both of them. Where i can collect the error messages from both. Please comment if you need more clarification on it. For now I just need to wrap them in a function which will return the corresponding error messages if they exist.

Comment: Is the second function missing `fields.` ? The first one has that

Comment: You should read here to don't do useless code https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/native-form-validation-part-1-bf8e35099f1d

Comment: My question could be much simpler as , How to wrap two different function into one using javascript and execute them by returning true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you have written two function `validateTIN and validateSINo` and these two functions are returning boolean. 
Similarly make your current functions i.e.`validationofTaxIDField` and `validationofSocialInsuranceField` return boolean, true when pass and false when failing.

and use these two later functions as they are returning boolean, you can AND them and get the required validation met!

```js
validationofTaxIDField(e, formDataArray) {
    console.log("WorkflowDisplay: validateTaxIDField: e", e, formDataArray);
    let alertError = false;
    if (formDataArray && formDataArray[0] && formDataArray[0]["1"] && formDataArray[0]["1"].taxInformation) {
      const ti = formDataArray[0]["1"].taxInformation;
      console.log("ti", ti);
      if (ti.taxId && !validateTIN(ti.taxId)) {
        alertError = true;
      }
    }
    return alertError;
  }
  validationofSocialInsuranceField(e, formDataArray) {
    console.log("WorkflowDisplay:validateSocialInsuranceField: e", e, formDataArray);
    let alertError = false;
    if (formDataArray && formDataArray[0] && formDataArray[0]["2"] && formDataArray[0]["2"].insuranceDetails) {
      const iid = formDataArray[0]["2"].insuranceDetails;
      console.log("WorkflowDisplay:validateSocialInsuranceField:iid", iid);
      if (iid.insuranceId && !validateSINo(iid.insuranceId)) {
        alertError = true;
      }
    }
    return alertError;
  }

wrapper(e, formDataArray) {
  if (this.validationofTaxIDField(e, formDataArray) && this.validateSocialInsuranceField(e, formDataArray)) {
    //do some forward stuff
  } else {
    //show validation error on screen
  }
}
```

Comment: I am very new to javascript. Can you help me with a code snippet. What will be the arguments we will be passing for the wrapper function. Thankyou.

Comment: added code snippet, let me know if you are able to get it or have some other query